# How to submit jwt token to Spring Security with ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, jwt

I have secured my API-endpoints of my Spring Boot Application with Spring Security.

On login, I generate a new jwt token and submit it to the user.

On data requests, I expect the user to submit the token in the header.

If I do this using postman, it works perfecty fine.
When I try to send the token with React, it fails (axios/fetch/superagent).
The issue is not the submission of the token itself because if I disable authorization I can read the authorization header with the controller.

Instead, Spring Security somehow does not recognize the header when it is sent via React.

I've tried adding another custom header to see if Spring allows that but that custom header is "blocked" aswell.

React:

```
axios(apiTest, {
      async: true,
      crossDomain: true,
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.props.token}`,
        TestHeader: "RandomValue",
        Accept: "*/*"
      },
      processData: false,
      data: ""
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data !== undefined) {
          console.log(res.data);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(error));
```

Spring Security:
Token Filter:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                //Usual Authorization header (is null with React-use)
                final String requestHeader = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
                //Custom header (null)
                System.out.println("Test Header: " + request.getHeader("TestHeader"));
        if (requestHeader != null && requestHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = requestHeader.substring(7);
            JwtAuthentication authentication = new JwtAuthentication(authToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
}
```

Config:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
                authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class).csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/Login").permitAll().antMatchers("/CloseConnection**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler);
    }
}
```

Any idea what the exact issue is and how to solve it?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem, with Postman works well but in ReactJS/Axios the `Authorization` never gets sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it worked for me

```
   private String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");     
            if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                return authHeader.replace("Bearer ","");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

axios call

```
axios.post(url,{
     "data": 'sample',
    },
    {
      headers: {
      'Authorization':'Bearer '+token,
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```